# SQL is throwing a syntax error with prepared statements "near '?,?,?,?) at line 1

Tags: php, mysql, sql, xampp

My goal is to send a user's login information to a XAMPP SQL Database. The data gets there successfully but the program throws the error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '?,?,?,?)' at line 1"

I have been searching for an answer to this specific issue but I have not found a solution yet.

```
    $password = $_POST['pwd'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $username = $_POST['uid'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users(idUsers, uidUsers, emailUsers, 
    pwdUsers) VALUES (?,?,?,?);";
    $idnum = "";
    $hashpwd = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssss",$idnum, $username, $email, 
    $hashpwd);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    if(!mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){

        die(mysqli_error($conn));
        exit();

    }

        else{
            echo("YAY");
    }
```

The PHP and SQL error logs are not showing anything and I've checked for errors throughout the rest of the code, this is the only part that is throwing errors. 
There seem to be a lot of posts about this topic. I have looked through many of them and I cannot find this issue.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You bind 6 values but the statement expect 4 values

Comment: Should the last **;** within  `"INSERT INTO users(idUsers, uidUsers, emailUsers, 
    pwdUsers) VALUES (?,?,?,?);"` be there?

Comment: @MsuArven, if i see clearly, only 4 values are bound

Comment: @T.Mas I have not seen it make a difference but I removed it to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already executed your query with the call to `mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)`; the call to `mysqli_query` is failing because that function is for the execution of normal (not prepared) queries, so the `?` in `$sql` are not being replaced. You should be checking the return status of the call to mysqli_stmt_execute instead:

```
if(!mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
    die(mysqli_error($conn));
    exit();
}
else{
    echo("YAY");
}
```